# Fast FEM Solvers

Tags: algorithm, solver

What are the fast solvers for [FEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) equations? I would prefer open source implementation, but if there is a commercial implementation, then I won't mind paying for it.

Comment: Do you have the matrix constructed ? If so, any sparse solver will do. I'm a happy user of the GMRES method. Biconjugate gradient works fine too, provided you use a stabilized version. Gauss-XX methods have poor convergence rates here. And above all, *use a good preconditioner*. Or use a dumb preconditioner at least (the diagonal part usually works fine).

Answer (score 4):

Code Aster is an open source FE code. [code aster](http://www.code-aster.org)

The pre- and post-processing is usually done with Salome - both originate from EDF.

Answer (score 2):

How about [FEAP](http://www.ce.berkeley.edu/~rlt/feap/). It has full source code available when you purchase it. It is pretty big project, maybe its too much for your needs, but check it out.

> FEAP is a general purpose finite
>   element analysis program which is
>   designed for research and educational
>   use. Source code of the full program
>   is available for compilation using
>   Windows (Compaq or Intel compiler),
>   LINUX or UNIX operating systems, and
>   Mac OS X based Apple systems.

It has also a Personal Edition called [FEAPpv](http://www.ce.berkeley.edu/~rlt/feappv/) available for free, including source code. Differences between those versions are listed in [this pdf](http://www.ce.berkeley.edu/~rlt/feappv/differ.pdf).

Comment: I think that the link is dead... http://projects.ce.berkeley.edu/feap/

Answer (score 2):

"brad"?  do you mean "broad"?

you don't say if your problem is linear or non-linear.  that'll make a very big difference.

the solver depends on the type of equation and the size of your problem.  for elliptical pdes you can choose standard linear algebra techniques like lu decomposition, iterative methods like successive over relaxation, or wavefront solvers that minimize memory consumption.

some people like solving non-linear steady-state problems as if they were dynamics problems.  the idea is to create "fake" mass and damping matricies and use explicit time integration to converge to steady state.

lots of choices.  standard linear algebra is a good starting point.

language?  java?

Answer (score 1):

Oops, that's kind of a brad question.

Solving differential equations usually starts with analyzing equation itself. Some equations are notoriously difficult to solve efficiently, e.g. indifinite boundary problems.
So if you have something else than an elliptic problem, you'll might better prepare for hard times ahead.

Next important and crutial part is transfering the contiouus problem into a discrete mesh. Typically the accuracy of your results will vary with different ways to generate this mesh. You'll need some sound experience here.

So I'd say there is nothing like *the* fast slover for FEM equations. Anyway, while [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element) gives a short overview of the topic, you might perhaps also have a look a the [german Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-Elemente-Methode) page. It lists well-known FEM implementations.

Answer (score 1):

OpenFoam and Elmer are two open source solvers.  Not sure about Elmer, but I think OpenFoam might uses the control volume approach.

Comment: Elmer is finite element, OpenFOAM is finite volume

Answer (score 1):

I used OpenFOAM for fluid dynamics research. You can do parallel processing with it with MPI. And if you have a Cray T3E it will be fast! 
It's open source :D
http://www.opencfd.co.uk/openfoam/features.html#features

Answer (score 1):

Please have look for Deal.II open source library:

http://www.dealii.org/

They provide also VirtualBox image which comes pre-installed libs.